# Wildfly 8, problems with UriInfo context on async method

Tags: java, asynchronous, jax-rs, wildfly-8

I'm having problems converting one method to async. I'm using wildfly 8.2.0, and this method works just fine:

```
@GET
@Path("externalCallback")
@Produces("text/html")
public Response authorize(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, @QueryParam(value =        
    "code") final String code,
    @QueryParam(value = "state") final String state) {

        URI baseUri = uriInfo.getBaseUri();
        final URI redirect = UriBuilder.fromUri(baseUri)
            .path("auth.html").build();        

        if (!validateAntiForgeryStateToken(state)) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Invalid anti forgery state token");
        }

        return Response.seeOther(redirect).build();
    }
```

but if i convert it to assync, this fails with the error Unable to find contextual data of type javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo

```
@GET
@Path("externalCallback")
@Produces("text/html")
@Asynchronous
public void authorize(@Suspended
final AsyncResponse asyncResponse, @Context
final UriInfo uriInfo, @QueryParam(value = "code")
final String code, @QueryParam(value = "state")
final String state) {

    asyncResponse.resume(doAuthorize(uriInfo, code, state));
}

private Response doAuthorize(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, @QueryParam(value = "code") final String code, @QueryParam(value = "state") final String state) {
    URI baseUri = uriInfo.getBaseUri();
    final URI redirect = UriBuilder.fromUri(baseUri)
            .path("auth.html").build();        

    if (!validateAntiForgeryStateToken(state)) {
        throw new WebApplicationException("Invalid anti forgery state token");
    }

    return Response.seeOther(redirect).build();
}
```

I've tried to change the `doAuthorize` method signature, changing the `UriInfo` to an `URI`, and passing the value extracted on the authorize method, but even in this case it fails with the same error.

Anyone knows why is this happening ? is it supposed to work that way ?

Here is the full call stack of the error (taken from wildfly log file)

here is the full call stack

```
12:29:14,084 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (EJB default - 1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component SecurityTokenService for method public void com.mindedsolutions.brownsea.services.SecurityTokenService.authorize(javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo,java.lang.String,java.lang.String): javax.ejb.EJBException: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:340) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:448)
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.processInvocation(LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.java:79) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory$1$2.runInvocation(AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory.java:97) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncInvocationTask.run(AsyncInvocationTask.java:73) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ContextParameterInjector$GenericDelegatingProxy.invoke(ContextParameterInjector.java:53) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.getBaseUri(Unknown Source)
at com.mindedsolutions.brownsea.services.SecurityTokenService.doExternalAuthentication(SecurityTokenService.java:109) [classes:]
at com.mindedsolutions.brownsea.services.SecurityTokenService.externalAuthentication(SecurityTokenService.java:105) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:273) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
... 38 more
```

Comment: Why don't you share the error?

Comment: full call stack is now on the question

Answer (score 0):

Once you send it into async mode, there is no context associated with the `UriInfo`. In other words, the `UriInfo` needs to be accessed from within a request scope/context.

The only way around it is to retrieve the `URI` before going into async. Then do your processing with that `URI`

```
public void authorize(@Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse, 
                      @Context UriInfo uriInfo, 
                      @QueryParam(value = "code") String code,
                      @QueryParam(value = "state") String state) {

    URI uri = uriInfo.getBaseUri();
    asyncResponse.resume(doAuthorize(uri, code, state));
}
```